# How can I get the list of mercurial patches that would apply cleanly in a linear order?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, revision-history

I'm looking for a command that will output a list of sequential patches that would apply cleanly if the repository was in a specific known earlier state. Here's an `hg glog` of a repository that contains some issues I've run into (also available from https://bitbucket.org/dusty/funny_repo/ if you want to play with it your own clone):

```
@  changeset:   8:ffd749c92f3b
|  tag:         tip
|  summary:     h
|
o    changeset:   7:bc959885f6aa
|\   parent:      6:dfe021fa52a4
| |  parent:      5:4d8bc738f0ab
| |  summary:     MERGE
| |
| o  changeset:   6:dfe021fa52a4
| |  parent:      3:1374ea53e7b7
| |  summary:     e
| |
o |  changeset:   5:4d8bc738f0ab
| |  branch:      branch2
| |  summary:     g
| |
o |  changeset:   4:e46fa4632d36
|/   branch:      branch2
|    summary:     f
|
o  changeset:   3:1374ea53e7b7
|  summary:     d
|
o  changeset:   2:59712a781f0c
|  branch:      branch1
|  summary:     c
|
o  changeset:   1:ff7f8724ad17
|  branch:      branch1
|  summary:     b
|
o  changeset:   0:a3b3a87aa422
   summary:     a
```

Essentially, I want to know what revset to pass to `hg export` in order to output changesets 0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 7, and 8. I don't want changesets 4 and 5 because the 'effect' of those changesets is applied in the merge commit in changeset 6.

`ancestors(default)` outputs all the changesets, but `branch('default')` ignores changesets 1 and 2, which, while on a different branch, are required for the patches to apply cleanly.

Obviously for this instance I could use `hg log -r "0..default and not branch(branch2)"` but I am looking for a more general command revset that will work in all the cases.

For testing, I am using the command `hg export -r "0..default and not branch(branch2)" -o ../%R.patch` and the following for loop to apply the resulting patches:

```
cd ../
mkdir patched
cd patched
for n in ../*.patch ; do
    patch -p1 <$n
done
```

Comment: Do you need the patches to be applied separately?  Or could you export a single patch that showed the cumulative differences between the first and last changesets?

Comment: I'd like them to be listed separately. I know how to get the diff between any two repo states already.

Comment: I've had a play, and can't find a way that would work other than specifically excluding `branch2`. The problem I can see is that if you could find a solution (always pick the `default` branch), it wouldn't work if you had two unnamed branches, which is very much a possibility (probably more-so than named branches depending on your workflow?). In these cases you would be wanting to pick the `default` branch, but that could be either.

Answer (score 0):

More general attempt:

- still require one preliminary human-check and configuration action;
- will work only with relatively new Mercurial, where p(1|2) functions added to revsets

Pre-check: for repository with mergeset you have to define, which parent-line of mergeset you want to use, p1(MERGESET) and p2(MERGESET) will show "Who is who"; and remeber revsion on mergeset. For you test-case

```
hg log -r "p1(7)"
changeset:   6:dfe021fa52a4
parent:      3:1374ea53e7b7
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:54:01 2012 -0700
summary:     e

hg log -r "p2(7)"
changeset:   5:4d8bc738f0ab
branch:      branch2
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:53:55 2012 -0700
summary:     g
```

and just note: p1 line will must to survive.

- Exclusion of something is "x - y" (or "x and ! y", but first form is just readable)
- x in our case is full history

(`0:tip`),

y - all *indirect relatives* of p1(7)

`! (ancestors(p1(7)) | descendants(p1(7)))`

- Final revset becomes `"0:tip - ! (ancestors(p1(7)) | descendants(p1(7)))"`

Test-run of revset on you repository

```
hg log -r "0:tip - ! (ancestors(p1(7)) | descendants(p1(7)))"
changeset:   0:a3b3a87aa422
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:51:43 2012 -0700
summary:     a

changeset:   1:ff7f8724ad17
branch:      branch1
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:52:25 2012 -0700
summary:     b

changeset:   2:59712a781f0c
branch:      branch1
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:52:27 2012 -0700
summary:     c

changeset:   3:1374ea53e7b7
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:52:36 2012 -0700
summary:     d

changeset:   6:dfe021fa52a4
parent:      3:1374ea53e7b7
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:54:01 2012 -0700
summary:     e

changeset:   7:bc959885f6aa
parent:      6:dfe021fa52a4
parent:      5:4d8bc738f0ab
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:54:20 2012 -0700
summary:     MERGE

changeset:   8:ffd749c92f3b
tag:         tip
user:        Dusty Phillips <dusty@buchuki.com>
date:        Mon Dec 17 17:54:25 2012 -0700
summary:     h
```

### Final Edit

I recall lessons of formal logic: I have double negation in expession "x - ! SET" (in x but not in not set) is **just SET**. Purified revset is plain and clean

```
"ancestors(p1(7)) | descendants(p1(7))"
```

(it was also trailing `| p1(7)` initially, but *now* /`Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 2.4.2)`/, for unknown by me reasons, changeset is an ancestor and descendant of himself: `hg log -r "ancestors(p1(7)) & descendants(p1(7))"` returns changeset 6)